# What to do if a breastfeeding toddler vomits?

Tags: toddler, breastfeeding, vomiting

My daughter has thrown up a lot 2 days ago from 6pm-3am,

- 6am she was fed 9oz at once (not my choice),
- she threw all of it up.
- fed her less pedialite at a time, around 10am she threw up again, a
  lot, including yellowish stuff
- took her to doc, doc said it's stomach virus but should be ok soon
- she didnt eat anything for 3 hours, then we started giving her 1
  tablespoon, then 2 tablespoons, then 1oz every 5-10 mins. She also
  had a few naps and was feeling better.
- to sleep easier she was breastfed
- at 5am today she threw up again.

She has tears and her lips are fine so she is hydrated well enough. She's not peeing much but has liquid diarrhea. Also temperature has been normal throughout.

1. Should we continue to breastfeed?
2. Are we doing anything wrong?

I am a little scared since this is 2nd day and she threw up (first time since yesterday 10am).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your doctor hasn't instructed otherwise:

As long as she isn't throwing up immediately, every time she takes even a few sips, yes, continue breastfeeding.  It will likely be helpful to feed smaller amounts more often until she is feeling better.  And as always, if worried, call your doctor for advice.  Having actually examined your daughter, he'd be the most reliable resource.

The below link has a lot of information regarding vomiting in small children.

**[How to Handle Child Vomiting - Ask Dr. Sears](http://www.askdrsears.com/topics/health-concerns/childhood-illnesses/vomiting)**

The first thing to remember is **DON’T PANIC**.  Child vomiting is usually not dangerous and only rarely results in significant dehydration. Keep in mind it usually takes at least 12 hours of severe vomiting to make a child significantly dehydrated. These guidelines should help you get your child through the vomiting stage of his illness:

**First stage – severe vomiting every 5 – 30 minutes**

- During this time, do not attempt to give your child any food or
  liquids at all because they will just come right back up. This is
  called total bowel rest. Let the worst of the vomiting pass.
- If your child asks to nurse or drink something, then just offer
  small sips at a time, and don’t expect him to keep it down.

**Second stage – vomiting has started to slow down to every one or two hours**

- Go ahead and offer your child small sips of liquids every 5 or 10
  minutes. Here are the three best liquids to try:
- Oral electrolyte solution such as Pedialyte has the best balance of
  salt, sugar, and other electrolytes
- Frozen Popsicle or slushy made from an electrolyte solution
- Breastmilk is excellent for the nursing baby
- A few other suggestions until you can get an electrolyte solution:
  White grape juice or slushy slightly diluted with water. Gatorade or
  similar drink. Again, these are not as ideal, and should be replaced
  with Pedialyte when possible.
- Liquids NOT to give – apple, pear, and cherry juice may have too much
  sugar. This can worsen diarrhea and dehydration.

**Third stage – vomiting is now only 2 – 4 times a day or stopped altogether**

- It is now okay to try some foods.
- Bland foods such as crackers, toast, soup broth, etc.
- Continue breastfeeding.
- Restart formula if formula feeding. You can mix half formula and half
  Pedialyte at first. This may be more easily tolerated.
- Continue liquids as described above.
- Don’t be alarmed if your child throws up this food. It may be too
  soon to start feeding again. Just take a step back to the second
  stage until the vomiting calms down again.

Comment: awesome, this is basically the time table i was looking for, i tried searching but too many random results